# Deconstruction is ambiguous

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

I have a vector class with two deconstruction methods as follows:

```
public readonly struct Vector2
{
    public readonly double X, Y;

    ...

    public void Deconstruct( out double x, out double y )
    {
        x = this.X;
        y = this.Y;
    }

    public void Deconstruct( out Vector2 unitVector, out double length )
    {
        length = this.Length;
        unitVector = this / length;
    }
}
```

Somewhere else I have:

```
Vector2 foo = ...
(Vector2 dir, double len) = foo;
```

This gives me:

```
CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Vector2.Deconstruct(out double, out double)' and 'Vector2.Deconstruct(out Vector2, out double)'
```

How is this ambiguous?

Edit: Calling Deconstruct manually works fine:

```
foo.Deconstruct( out Vector2 dir, out double len );
```

Comment: If your Vector class had implicit conversion to/from a double, say, then this would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is by design in C#. Overloads of Deconstruct must have different arity (number of parameters), otherwise they are ambiguous.

> Pattern-matching does not have a left-hand-side. More elaborate
>   pattern-matching scheme is to have a parenthesized list of patterns to
>   match, and **we use the number of patterns to decide which Deconstruct
>   to use**.
>   - Neal Gafter https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1998#issuecomment-438472660

Comment: @Chris Yeah, looks like they decided to not use the type declarations for overload resolution in part so the type declarations can use `var`.